# gulp deploy-azure-storage hangs during file upload

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I have been following the tutorials for creating custom sharepoint webparts. I am at the point where I want to upload my sharepoint app to my azure storage container but when I execute the "gulp deploy-azure-storage" command, the file upload just hangs. Has anyone else encountered this problem?